# Change the class of a div based on video source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I'm trying to show and hide a div based on a certain video source. I have a bigvideo.js videos slideshow running and I want to show and hide divs based on the video playing. The code I'm using is

```
function checkClass() {
    setTimeout(checkClass, 100);
    if (jQuery('#big-video-vid_html5_api').src('http://localhost:8888/mobilwave/images/video1.mp4'))
        jQuery('.demo').css('visibility', 'visible');
    else if (!jQuery('#big-video-vid_html5_api').src('http://localhost:8888/mobilwave/images/video2.mp4'))
        jQuery('.demo').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

jQuery(checkClass);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method as `$.fn.src()`, to get the attribute, you need to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1)

```
function checkClass() {
    setTimeout(checkClass, 100);
    var src = jQuery('#big-video-vid_html5_api').attr('src');
    if (src == 'http://localhost:8888/mobilwave/images/video1.mp4')
        jQuery('.demo').css('visibility', 'visible');
    else
        jQuery('.demo').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

jQuery(checkClass);
```

Comment: Thanks @Satpal ! working! I have voted +1 but my reputation is not big enough to make a difference.